# Accessing HttpSession in PreProcessInterceptor

Tags: resteasy, httpsession

Is it possible to access/create the `HttpSession` in the `preProcess` method of a `PreProcessInterceptor`?

(RestEasy 2.3.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `HttpSession` by injecting the `HttpServletRequest` using the `@Context` annotation and then getting the session from the request like so:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
        throws Failure, WebApplicationException 
{       
    HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession();

    //Do something with the session here...
}
```